# Padding from left in C# console

Tags: c#, console-application, padding

Currently I'm trying to print some information in the console, but I'm trying to give all results the same padding.

Here an example, you can see CurrentBuildNumber result has one /t to much. /t is only to align everything out, it could be anything else. 
[image: Example screenshot]

So, i need a "fixed" padding for the : [result]. How can i do this correctly in my code?

Thanks!

Code:

```
        RegistryKey registryKeys = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows NT\\CurrentVersion");

        foreach (string registryKey in registryKeys.GetValueNames())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(registryKey + "\t\t: " + registryKeys.GetValue(registryKey));
        }
```

Comment: In the screenshot? :P Wait, I'll add.

Comment: Thanks. The [help] pages specifically say "Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem — and **include valid code to reproduce it — in the question itself**. See SSCCE.org for guidance." (**emphasis mine**). A screen image is not "code in the question itself" (just for future reference). :)

Comment: I'm sorry! Thanks for the notice :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use .PadRight(30) on the labels for example.

[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.padright?view=netframework-4.8](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.string.padright?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: Thanks! This answered my question :). Damn, that i didn't find this on  internet!

Answer (score 13):

Use string.Format() or just Console.Write() as it has support for formats

```
const string format = "{0,-32} :{1}";

Console.WriteLine(format, "Key", "Value")
```

the format value -32 means that key should take 32 positions and aligned to the left.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var key = "SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows NT\\CurrentVersion";
RegistryKey registryKeys = 
    Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(key);
var maxLength = registryKeys.GetValueNames().Max(n => n.Length);
foreach (string registryKey in registryKeys.GetValueNames())
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}:{1}", 
        registryKey.PadRight(maxLength), 
        registryKeys.GetValue(registryKey));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Console.WriteLine(registryKey.PadRight(20, ' ') + registryKeys.GetValue(registryKey));

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/66f6d830(v=vs.110).aspx